# How do you get the Pull request Variable from Github to use in Azue Devops Yaml Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to run a pipeline when a pull request is triggered on master branch from github.

I am using azure devops to run the pipeline

I want to pass the pull request number from github to use as a variable in the azure devops yaml pipeline

Can this be done?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you get the Pull request Variable from Github to use in Azue Devops Yaml Pipeline?

You could use the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services) `System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber` to get the pull request number from github.

```
pr:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- script: |
    echo The PullRequest Number is that: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)
  displayName: 'Get the PullRequest Number'
```

You should create YAML file for the github with above scripts:

[image]

The test result:

[image]